# Find out which percentile a number has

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

Say I have the following vector:

```
m<-c(11, 14, 11, 12, 11, 12,  9, 12, 12,  9, 12,  8, 11, 12, 10)
```

From this, it is easy to determine which number corresponds to a certain percentile, which has been demonstrated before (see: [Link 1](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/numerical-measures/percentile) or [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659528/how-to-get-nth-percentile-using-r-summary)). For example, if I wanted to know which number is at the 14th percentile I could write something along the following lines:

```
quantile(m, c(.14)) # this yields 9 as outcome
```

What do I do, however, if I already know the number (here: 9) and what to know which percentile of the given data this is? In other words, is there a way in R that allows me to determine which percentile of my data the number 9 corresponds to? Of course I can do this by manually changing the percentile until it corresponds with the desired number, but that seems quite cumbersome. Is there perhaps a more efficient way?

Comment: You could do `res <- quantile(m,  seq(0, 1, 0.01)) ; res[res == 9]`

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. Apologies duplicating an already existing post, I hadn't come across that in my search.